# Curvature of the curve added by normal vector

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

In a question, it's desired to find the curvature of a curve

$γ_r(t)=γ(t)+rN(t)$

in terms of $κ$ (the curvature of the **planar curve $γ$**) and the real number $r$. ($N(t)$ is the normal vector of $γ$).

Does it really have a good representation? I tried so much but didn't succeed!

It reminded me the concept of Bertrand curve. it didn't help me, though.

I think it's also OK if it includes tangent vecotor, normal vector, derivatives of the curve, etc. But probably the simplest answer is considered.

Comment: Is it a space curve? Or a planar curve?

Comment: @PratikApshinge Oh, I just noticed that it's a plane curve ‍♂️. I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First show that
$$\dot\gamma_r(t)=\dot\gamma(t)\bigl(1-r\kappa(t)\bigr).$$
Compute $\ddot\gamma(t)$.  You'll arrive in a pretty nice expression for $\kappa_r$ which includes only $\kappa$ and $r$, but not the derivative of $\kappa$.

Hint: use
$$\kappa(t)=\frac{\langle\ddot\gamma,J\dot\gamma\rangle}{\|\dot\gamma\|^3},$$
where $J(a,b):=(-b,a)$.

Answer (score 1):

In simpler terms for plane curves $ (\tau =0) $ the Frenet- Serret relations ( primed on arc )

$$ N' = -\kappa T; T'= \kappa N ;\to N''=- \kappa^2 N $$

$$\kappa^2= -\frac{N''}{N} \text{ wrt arc}$$

Wrt general parameterization $t$ see at bottom of wiki  [Curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#:%7E:text=Intuitively%2C%20the%20curvature%20describes%20for,larger%20this%20rate%20of%20change.)

For rectangular coordinates when normal makes $\phi$ to positive x-axis

$$ \phi= \tan^{-1}\frac{dy}{dx}\;; \kappa = \phi'.$$

Comment: Yeah, it's a matrix differential equation.
\begin{gather}
\begin{bmatrix}T'\\N'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & κ \\-κ & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}Τ\\Ν\end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
The formula $N''= -κ^2N$ can also be proved by take derivative from both sides of the equation. But the question is that can we do that? Since the curvature is also a function of $t$. Why doesn't it include the derivative of the matrix multiplied by the vector $[T,N]^t$?

Comment: Edited in answer.